# Localizer ASP.NET Core 6 will not be saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-localization

I have a problem with my Localizer. If I want to change the language of the website from English to Dutch, the POST request does get sent (checked with debugging). Only the language always remains set to English and is not changed to Dutch.

I got the code from Microsoft's own documentation, and I don't understand why it doesn't work. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/make-content-localizable?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

I am using ASP.NET Core 6.

This is my `program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Application") ??
                          throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string not found")));

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Users");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(connectionString ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string not found")));

builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(config =>
        config.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis"));
builder.Services.AddSession();
}

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
});

builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "nl" };
    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[1])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
});

builder.Services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
builder.Services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AuthMessageSenderOptions"));


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
{
    var questStringCultureProvider = options.RequestCultureProviders[0];    
    options.RequestCultureProviders.RemoveAt(0);
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(1, questStringCultureProvider);
});

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "name",
        pattern: "{name}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "",
        defaults: new { controller="Home", action="Choose" });
});

app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseSession();

app.Run();
```

My shared layout file (`_layout.cshtml`):

```
@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}
<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
                            <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home"
                                  asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl"
                                  method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                <label asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name">@Localizer["Language:"]</label>
                                <select name="culture"
                                        onchange="this.form.submit();"
                                        asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems">
                                </select>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

And the `HomeController.cs`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl) 
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
    );

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: If the POST request to your `SetLanguage` endpoint is not being sent then your problem has nothing to do with localization and you just need to fix the request so it is sent (and received) properly. What do you mean when you say you "checked with debugging". How did you debug this? What did you find out?

Comment: I put a brakepointer on this method:
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl) ...

and it executed everything correctly.

Comment: I don't see where you are creating/injecting an IStringLocalizer in your pages ... can you clarify where/how you are doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure if `Response.Cookies.Append()` set the cookie correctly, you can check browser's developer tools to see if the Set-Cookie header contains the expected cookie with the language information.

Comment: I had a quick look and the cookie stores the correct option when updating the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below(don't configure RequestLocalizationOptions part when you regist services,part in middleware):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);

builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-us", "nl" };
    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[1])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
    var questStringCultureProvider = options.RequestCultureProviders[0];
    options.RequestCultureProviders.RemoveAt(0);
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(1, questStringCultureProvider);
    //Add services to the container.
});


var app = builder.Build();


app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

It now works well on myside:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change every `@Localizer["......."]` to `@Localizer["......."].Value`